# Could not propose [stringformat] as a synonym for [string-formatting], due to proposed synonym on *third* tag

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonym-process

The [stringformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stringformat) tag only has 200 posts, and no tag wiki, and its questions are clearly string formatting questions. So I wanted to add it as a synonym to the [string-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-formatting) tag (1740 posts, has a tag wiki).

However, I got an error message:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> A synonym from stringformat to string-formatting exists, chains are not allowed

<kbd>[image: error screenshot]</kbd>

but there are no [actual synonyms listed](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stringformat/synonyms) for the [stringformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stringformat) tag.

The error was caused by an existing [*proposed* tag synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276194/remove-string-formatting-tag-synonym-from-string) from [string-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-formatting) to [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) (thanks to [Braiam for finding that one](/a/276192)). The  error message was spectacularly failing to inform me of the real cause.

I was able to [propose the tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/string-formatting/synonyms) only when the [string-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-formatting) -> [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) synonym proposal was rejected.

Comment: Where ever the ghost is, it doesn't seem to be in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/243024) or it must be that string-formatting itself is synomized to string?

Comment: Could the absence of tag wiki caused the problem? (as in bug)

Comment: @nhahtdh: no, a tag wiki has no influence on this; plenty of tags have no tag wiki and can be made into synonyms just fine. I only mentioned the lack of the wiki here to illustrate that the [tag:stringformat] tag is the lesser of the two.

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug in the error string formatting logic.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Don't you mean a bug in the error string logic? Or is that a synonym? :)

Comment: @abarnert: Yeah, but I like this wording better cause it has "string formatting" like the question.

Comment: I don't know the mechanism behind tags but I'd also like to see [stringformat] and [string-formatting] tags merged into one tag.

Answer (score 30):

The message is misleading, but I know why it happens:

[image]

There's a pending suggested synonym for [string-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-formatting). The system reject it because it can't allow chains (stringformat -> string-formatting -> string).

The solution is dismiss the suggestion by either approving or rejecting it and then propose the synonym again.

Comment: BTW, is my personal opinion that it should be rejected.

Comment: Great detective work! Yeah, this probably is the root cause. The bug then, is in that error message as it doesn't tell me anything about the proposed synonym. I've voted against the proposed [tag:string-formatting] -> [tag:string] synonym now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the suggestion has been rejected. You can try again now.

Comment: Confirmed; the synonym proposal could be made now.