# Reject "string-formatting" as suggested tag synonym for "string"

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-process

I recently suggested [string-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-formatting) as a synonym for [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string). This has caused a problem as indicated at [Can't propose stringformat as a synonym for string-formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276172/369450).

Would the community members with enough reputation within that tag kindly [down vote](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/string/synonyms#syn-vote-table) my incorrectly suggested synonym of [string-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-formatting) in [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've already voted, and so did someone else, so this is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

[string-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-formatting) is a distinct enough area that it warrants having its own tag; otherwise you'll end up with a generic [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formatting) combo that doesn't quite do the subject justice on all those 1740 and growing posts.

My bug report still stands even if this was resolved; the error message is one of the most unhelpful on the site.